# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed using RijndaelManaged

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

when i trying to decrypt a string using PaddingMode.PKCS7 i'm getting 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed' exception, but when i try using PaddingMode.Zeros i'm not getting any exception.

P.S I've encrypted the script using PaddingMode.PKCS7 so i have to decrypt script using same PaddingMode.

```
if (encrypted == null || encrypted.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ecrypted");
            if (keyArr == null || keyArr.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("keyArr");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            using (RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged())
            {

                rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rij.KeySize = 128;
                rij.BlockSize = 128;

                rij.Key = keyArr;
                rij.IV = iv;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = rij.CreateDecryptor();

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
                    }
                    plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }

            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your code here so we can help you identify the issue.

Comment: Andy, I have provided the code, can you pls identify the issue.

Comment: You added the code to decrypt but not to encrypt. Without seeing that, my guess is that you are not properly encoding the cipher text as Base64 or hexadecimal and that is why data is getting corrupted. Using encodings such as UTF-8 or ASCII for cipher text will lead to byte sequences being interpreted as unprintable or control characters. Use a safe encoding as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually padding errors do not mean there is a padding error, rather it is a decryption error. When decryption fails the output is essentially random bytes and the padding will of course be incorrect.

Make sure:

1. All the same options are used, it is best to explicitly specify all options and not rely on defaults.
2. The encryption key is an exact allowable size, do not rely on key padding.
3. Any encodings of the encrypted data are handled correctly on encryption and decryption.